# XML column in SQL Server table - combine recurring tag name into one column

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have to query a XML data column in SQL Server and need some help with how I can query some of the individual tags inside the XML.

Here is a toy data set that I have been using to test my query:

```
<SampleData>
    <ColumnGroup Usage="INEQUALITY">
        <Column Name="col1"/>
    </ColumnGroup>
    <ColumnGroup Usage="INCLUDE">
        <Column Name="col2"/>
        <Column Name="col3"/>
        <Column Name="col4"/>
        <Column Name="col5"/>
    </ColumnGroup>
</SampleData>
```

The result I want to achieve from my query is as follows:

```
 CT1          CN1    CT2         CN2
 -----------------------------------------------------
 INEQUALITY   col1   INCLUDE     col2, col3, col4, col5
```

The issue I am having is being able to query the XML to put the column 'CN2' together. I have figured out a query to get the first 3 columns but not for the last (CN2).

Here the query I currently have (#queryPlan is the temp table I have created to store the XML, query_plan is the column with the XML):

```
SELECT 
    query_plan.value('(/SampleData/ColumnGroup/@Usage)[1]', 'varchar(max)') as [CT1],
    query_plan.value('(/SampleData/ColumnGroup/Column/@Name)[1]', 'varchar(max)') as [CN1],
    query_plan.value('(/SampleData/ColumnGroup/@Usage)[2]', 'varchar(max)') as [CT2]
FROM 
    #queryPlan
```

But I have had no luck coming up with the fourth column for this query. The problem I am having is combining the child tags into one single column. Any suggestions for how I might accomplish this? Thanks.

EDIT: Here is the answer that I was able to achieve.

```
SELECT  CT1 = t.query_plan.value('(SampleData/ColumnGroup/@Usage)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),
    CN1 = STUFF((SELECT CONCAT(',', i.X.value('@Name', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'))
                FROM    t.query_plan.nodes('SampleData/ColumnGroup[1]/Column') AS i (X)
                FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, ''),
    CT2 = t.query_plan.value('(SampleData/ColumnGroup/@Usage)[2]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),
    CN2 = STUFF((SELECT CONCAT(',', i.X.value('@Name', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'))
                FROM    t.query_plan.nodes('SampleData/ColumnGroup[2]/Column') AS i (X)
                FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
FROM    #queryPlan t;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to do this without first breaking the different elements into rows, adding the comma, then using `FOR XML PATH()` to concatenate the rows back to a single columns:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (X XML);
INSERT @T (X)
VALUES ('
<SampleData>
    <ColumnGroup Usage="INEQUALITY">
        <Column Name="col1"/>
    </ColumnGroup>
    <ColumnGroup Usage="INCLUDE">
        <Column Name="col2"/>
        <Column Name="col3"/>
        <Column Name="col4"/>
        <Column Name="col5"/>
    </ColumnGroup>
</SampleData>');

SELECT  CT1 = t.x.value('(SampleData/ColumnGroup/@Usage)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),
        CN1 = STUFF((SELECT CONCAT(',', i.X.value('@Name', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'))
                    FROM    t.X.nodes('SampleData/ColumnGroup[1]/Column') AS i (X)
                    FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, ''),
        CT2 = t.x.value('(SampleData/ColumnGroup/@Usage)[2]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),
        CN2 = STUFF((SELECT CONCAT(',', i.X.value('@Name', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'))
                    FROM    t.X.nodes('SampleData/ColumnGroup[2]/Column') AS i (X)
                    FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
FROM    @T t;
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked!. I had to make a few changes, and I will edit my question to show the answer I came up with.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
N'<SampleData>
  <ColumnGroup Usage="INEQUALITY">
    <Column Name="col1" />
  </ColumnGroup>
  <ColumnGroup Usage="INCLUDE">
    <Column Name="col2" />
    <Column Name="col3" />
    <Column Name="col4" />
    <Column Name="col5" />
  </ColumnGroup>
</SampleData>';
select @xml

SELECT cg.value('(@Usage)[1]', 'varchar(max)') as ColumnGroupUsage
      ,c.value('(@Name)[1]','varchar(max)') AS ColumnName
FROM @xml.nodes(N'SampleData/ColumnGroup') AS A(cg)
OUTER APPLY cg.nodes(N'Column') AS B(c)
```

The result

```
INEQUALITY  col1
INCLUDE     col2
INCLUDE     col3
INCLUDE     col4
INCLUDE     col5
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but not exactly. I need the result to be in a single row (not multiple columns) like I displayed in the question description. The reason I need this is because I there is multiple rows in the temp table #queryPlan that I need to get results for.

Comment: Multiple rows* not multiple columns

Answer (score 0):

If you need them in one column, separated by comma, then this is your code:

```sql
DECLARE @xml XML=
N'<SampleData>
  <ColumnGroup Usage="INEQUALITY">
    <Column Name="col1" />
  </ColumnGroup>
  <ColumnGroup Usage="INCLUDE">
    <Column Name="col2" />
    <Column Name="col3" />
    <Column Name="col4" />
    <Column Name="col5" />
  </ColumnGroup>
</SampleData>';
select @xml

SELECT 
    cg.value('(@Usage)[1]', 'varchar(max)')                 as CT1
    ,(  select ', ' + c1.value('(@Name)[1]','varchar(max)') 
        from cg.nodes(N'Column') as C(c1) 
        for xml path(''), type
        ).value('substring(text()[1], 2)', 'varchar(max)')  as CN1
    ,c.value('(@Usage)[1]', 'varchar(max)')                 as CT2
    ,(  select ', ' + c2.value('(@Name)[1]','varchar(max)') 
        from c.nodes(N'Column') as D(c2) 
        for xml path(''), type
        ).value('substring(text()[1], 2)', 'varchar(max)')  as CN2
FROM 
    @xml.nodes(N'SampleData/ColumnGroup[1]') as A(cg)
    cross apply @xml.nodes(N'SampleData/ColumnGroup[2]') as B(c)
```

The result is:
[Query Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9JKCG.png)

P.S. Edited the query to match exactly what you need.